# Post.create Method Incorrect # of Arguments (3 for 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, migration

I'm having an issue with a recent migration I placed on a table using `ActiveRecord`. This is the initial migration to create the table:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :content

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I added a field to it later with this migration:

```
class AddPrivateToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   add_column :posts, :private, :boolean
  end
end
```

Whenever I call `Post.create("Title", "Content", true)` or `Post.create!("Title", "Content", true)`, I get `too many arguments` error. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass a hash containing your desired attributes to `Post.create`, e.g. `Post.create(title: 'title', content: 'content', private: true)`

Ruby function calls can always end in a hash of arguments, and the hash notation `{ }` can be omitted. In this case, the hash is passed to the first argument of `create`, which is the attribute hash. Alternatively you can pass a hash explicitly, and further hash-like arguments are then passed to the second `options` parameter, e.g.

`Post.create({title: 'title', ...}, without_protection: true)`

API Reference [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) and [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class)

Comment: This worked. Thanks - didn't know this was a portion of rails' syntax.